# Visualize tables into QGIS maps?

Tags: qgis, table

I'm looking for a way to **show attributes** as number in **little tables** via QGIS. For example I want to show various facilities a city has with a small table. You can see the example of what I mean in this map made by me few weeks ago:

https://s-media-cache-ak0.pinimg.com/originals/ed/3c/9d/ed3c9d69948d3ef1d2b6f8b5a6903a49.jpg

https://www.pinterest.com/pin/473229873324662401/

The small table with icons showing the facilities of each city/commune is made via graphical editing software (CorelDraw). It would be great if I could find a way to make this via QGIS.

I know it's a quite complicated thing but I would like to know if there is at least any chance for this to happen.

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE.  As a new user, please be sure to take the [Tour](http://gis.stackexchange.com/tour). It is policy to ask one question per Question, and you effectively have two (QGIS and ArcGIS have very different answers).  Please **edit** your question to focus on QGIS (since there is already an answer), and remove the links to third-party images (which are less likely to be followed, and more likely to get broken over time) -- the editor has a simple interface to add images.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's a QGIS start. I have point data, with four attributes (hospital, police, fire, school) that are either 0 or 1. I use a point symbolizer with five layers - one simple symbol red point for the location and four SVG symbols for the facilities.

Each of the SVG layers has a different offset, and the size is determined by the attribute. So if hospital is 0, then the size is zero and the symbol disappears. Note the yellow button next to the "size" setting here showing data-define symbolism is in force. To set it, click and edit the expression to something like `hospital * 10` so that the size is 10 if hospital is 1, and zero if not:

[image: styling]

with that, you get this:

[image: grid attributes]

Another four layers could be used to show some boxes unconditionally so you have empty squares when facilities are not present. Adjust sizes and offsets and symbols to suit. Doing 16 of these as in your example looks a challenge though! It might get to the point where you could more easily write a custom Python Renderer for the job...

However, positioning the table optimally for each feature like in your example looks very tricky. As is, its always fixed in position relative to the feature, so might stomp on something important.

Another possibility is to construct a labelling string with an expression and use that. For my case, such an expression would be something like:

```
concat(
if(hospital=1,'ᛰ',' '),
if(fire=1,'ᛜ',' '),
'|',
if(police=1,'ᛞ',' '),
if(school=1,'ᚸ',' ')
)
```

Note I've used some runic symbols from a font - you could use H for hospitals, S for schools etc. The `|` in there is so you can tell QGIS to wrap the label at that point, then you get two rows of symbols. If you use a fixed-width font it will all line up, and set a coloured background to get something like this:

[image: use labels]

If you've got a font with the symbols you need then this is much easier than the symbology method above - Wingdings or Dingbats or something.

Comment: That sounds great, takes some time to get it done but it's possible :).